# IE charset issue In drupal

Tags: internet-explorer, character-encoding, drupal-7

I have drupal site which has content in Catalan language.

The content has special characters and symbols which are showing up in square shapes instead of exact characters or symbols in IE alone ,where are as in other browsers its working fine.

This is the char-set which i am using

```
'Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1,utf-8'
```

This works in all browsers except IE. I have attached the image over here.

[image]

Parent of this question is [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/85446/import-issue-in-other-languages-using-csv-file-to-drupal-node-creations)

Any help will be really appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `charset` parameter value must be a single name of an encoding, not a list. Apparently what happens is that some browsers use just the first part of the value whereas IE tries to match the entire value against a set of encoding names.

Most probably the document is actually iso-8859-1 or windows-1252 encoded, you should change the HTTP header to

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1252
```

Alternatively, and better in the long run, change the actual encoding to UTF-8 and the header to

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: There are some symbols which was not showing properly in all browsers,such as `, inverted single quotes etc.. so in order to avoid that i have used ISO-8859-1 char-set which retrieves and shows every character and symbol properly.Now only in IE it shows up like this. It doesn't show up properly with utf-8 charset. There is a parent question which made me to do like this.Any suggestions ?

Comment: @Ram, did you try either of the solutions I presented. The first one should be very easy to test.

Comment: Yes, i changed charset to be like this(Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1252) as you said  and it seems to be working :-) But i dont know what was the issue earlier??

Comment: UTF-8 is generally approved standard, which works everywhere. Windows-any encoding is Windows-specific and not guaranteed to work on any machine.Is this right?? But with this char-set of windows-1252 for me this is working perfectly al-right in linux too. any idea how it does ?

Comment: Windows-1252 works on all browsers simply because browsers have to live in a world where windows-1252 is used so much. And declaring windows-1252 works remarkably better than declaring utf-8, when the data is in fact in windows-1252 encoding.

Comment: Thats great to hear :-) Thanks.